# How to calculate Duration from start and end time specified in textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used three textbox controls and in the first textbox i specify the start time and in second textbox i specify the end time and when the control moves to next textbox the duration should be automatically calculated. I have already seen some suggestions to use timespan but it doesn't work 100% perfectly. For example ,

If start time = 10.00 AM and end time = 03:00 PM the duration is calculated as 5 hrs correcly but if start time = 03:00 PM and end time = 01:00 AM then the duration = -14:00 in a wrong manner. The output i expect is = 10 hrs in clockwise direction but instead the time is calculated in anticlockwise direction and the output is wrong as -14:00. How to overcome this situation. I am posting the code i used below.

```
<div> 

    <asp:Label ID="lblStartTime" runat="server" Text="StartTime"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtstrtime" runat="server"  Width="88px" AutoPostBack="True" 
    Height="25px" ontextchanged="txtstrtime_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>        

    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtstrtime_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="txtstrtime" Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" 
    MaskType="Time" InputDirection="RightToLeft" Enabled="true" AcceptAMPM="true">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>

    <asp:Label ID="lblEndTime" runat="server" Text="EndTime"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtendtime" runat="server" Width="97px" Height="25px" 
    AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txtendtime_TextChanged"> 
    </asp:TextBox>       

    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtendtime_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
       Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="Time" 
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="txtendtime"  
    AcceptAMPM="true">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>       

    <asp:Label ID="lblduration" runat="server" Text="Duration"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtduration" runat="server" Width="112px" Height="27px" 
    ontextchanged="txtduration_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox> 

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

 </div>
```

and the code behind is

```
protected void txtendtime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime startTime, endTime;
        startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstrtime.Text);
        endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtendtime.Text);
        var timeDiff = new TimeSpan(endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks);
        txtduration.Text = Convert.ToString(timeDiff);
        txtduration.Focus();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    protected void txtendtime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime startTime, endTime;
            startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstrtime.Text);
            endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtendtime.Text);
            if (startTime > endTime)
                endTime = endTime.AddDays(1);
            TimeSpan span = (toDate - fromDate);
            double actualHours = Math.Round(span.TotalHours, 2);
            txtduration.Text = Convert.ToString(actualHours);
            txtduration.Focus();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: decimal actualHours = Math.Round(span.TotalHours, 2); This line doesn't work for me.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'

Comment: @Ezhilan there i changed it to double

Comment: What is the value of txtstrtime.Text and txtendtime.Text?

Comment: txtstrtime.text = 03:00 PM and txtendtime.text = 01:00 AM

Answer (score 2):

Add this above txtDuration.Text:

```
if (timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 0) {
      timeDiff.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}
```

Comment: AddDays is not acceptable. The message says 'System.Timespan' does not contain a definition for Adddays.

Comment: No problem but Still when i specify start time as 3.00 PM and end time as 01:00 AM the output i get is -14:00 hrs but i need 10:00 hrs.The answer i have accepted works correctly for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            DateTime startTime, endTime;
            TimeSpan timeDiff;
            startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstrtime.Text);;
            endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtendtime.Text);
            if (startTime > endTime)
            {
                timeDiff = new TimeSpan(startTime.Ticks - endTime.Ticks);
            }
            else
            {
                timeDiff = new TimeSpan(endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks);
            }
            txtduration.Text = Convert.ToString(timeDiff );
```

Comment: I want to use the time that i specify in textbox and not the system time.

Comment: But now when i specify 03:00 PM and 01:00 AM as start and end time the output i get is 14:00 but i need 10:00 hrs.